# texto sobresale del div

Tags: html, css, laravel, div

Tengo un div dentro del cual hay 4 botones, pero el texto sobresale del div al reducir la pantalla

mi html

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                {{ Form::button(nombre, ['class' => 'btn btn-giant btn-primary', 'id' => 'button', 'title' => 'Descriptio', 'onClick' => "submit"]) }}
            </div>
    </div>
```

Esta es mi css

```
.btn-giant {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40vh;
    font-size: 40px !important;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Intenta añadirle un  padding

Comment: reduce el tamaño de la fiente con un media query

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolverlo?

Comment: Es mejor que pongas el código HTML generado en lugar de el código que lo genera. De ese modo podremos ver el problema directamente en la pregunta y será más fácil ayudarte. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve]. Además, sería importante que aclarases cómo quieres que se vea al final, ¿quieres que el tamaño del texto se reduzca para entrar en el `div`? ¿quieres que el texto pase a tener varias líneas?

Comment: Lo solucione usando media query, segun la respuesta de @ReneLimon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que el tamaño de la fuente está fijo, sin importar el tamaño de la ventana.
Deberías hacer que según el tamaño del viewport cambie el tamaño de la fuente para que siempre entre el texto, o al menos hacer que sea proporcional a las dimensiones del navegador, algo así:

```
  .btn-giant {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40vh;
    font-size: 6vmin !important;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    color: red;
  }
```

En caso de usar estas medidas (vmin, vmax, vh, etc.) deberías ver la compatibilidad de los navegadores donde se vaya usar.  En este sitio podés verlo: [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!